# How access nested JSON node after converting from SOAP?

Tags: javascript, json, soap

Using node.js(javascript) how do I access the GetDataResult node in this JSON data that has been converted from SOAP data.

```
{
"s:Envelope": {
    "$": {
        "xmlns:s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    },
    "s:Body": [{
        "GetDataResponse": [{
            "$": {
                "xmlns": "http://tempuri.org/"
            },
            "GetDataResult": ["You entered: TEST"]
        }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Specific pages that you should read include [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please take these introductory steps and then edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test using [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) interactive mode :

```
$ node
> var x = {
... "s:Envelope": {
.....     "$": {
.......         "xmlns:s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
.......     },
.....     "s:Body": [{
.......         "GetDataResponse": [{
.........             "$": {
...........                 "xmlns": "http://tempuri.org/"
...........             },
.........             "GetDataResult": ["You entered: TEST"]
.........         }]
.......     }]
.....   }
... }
undefined
> console.log(x["s:Envelope"]["s:Body"][0]["GetDataResponse"][0]["GetDataResult"][0])
```

### Output :

```
'You entered: TEST'
```

### Explanations :

I try to elaborate a bit from comments below. There is no *container*, I try to explain :

You have to think [json](/questions/tagged/json) like what it is : an *object* or a *data structure*.

In [python](/questions/tagged/python), we would say it's a *dict*, in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) a *hash table* etc... Globally, it's all about *associative array*

So when you see in JSON :

```
"key" : { "value" }
```

it's an *associative array*

If instead you see

```
"key": [
    { "key1": "foo" },
    { "key2": "bar" },
    { "key3": "base" }
]
```

It's an *array of hashes* or *array of associative arrays*.

When you access a simple *associative array* without spaces or odd characters, you can (in [js](/questions/tagged/js) do :

```
variable.key
```

In your case, you have odd character `:` in the key name, so `x.s:Envelope` wouldn't work. Instead we write: `x['s:Envelope']`.

And as far as you have *arrays of associative arrays* inside  `[]`, you have to tell `js` which array number you need to fetch. It's arrays with only one *associative array*, so it's simple, we go deeper in the *data structure* by passing array number, that's what we've done with

```
x['s:Envelope']["s:Body"][0]
                          ^
                          |
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you for taking the time to post an answer to my problem.

Comment: Try to understand what's going on.

Comment: From your solution I would say the s:Envelope is the overall container.  And I am requesting the first value of s:body.  Then the first value of GetDataResponse.  Then the first value of GetDataResult.  Feel free to elaborate if I have it wrong.

Comment: Added explanations about data structure and how to fetch them